# UIImageViews in NSMutable Arrays

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am in the process of making the game Avalanche for the iPod family. I have my random objects appearing at the top and dropping down with a set of lines that go like this :

```
[UIView setAnimationsDidStopSelector:@Selector(onAnimationComplete:finished:context:)];  
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];  
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

I have also created a UIImageView like so:

```
UIImageview* debrisView= [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: debris];
```

I want to put the debrisView in a array and iterate through to see the frame (or coordinates). I want to be able to compare the coordinates to where the player is to see if they touch and what not (therefore the game is over). How would I add multiple (more than 500) "debrisView" to an array, compare the frame within the array to a moveable UIImageView.. say named player to see if the coordinates of the falling debris are a match or touching with the player? And as far as memory goes, how do I get rid of "debrisView" in my array when the object touches the bottom screen? Could somebody please point me in the right direction or even explain this all to me? I am really new to Objective - C. Much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

-Dustin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as memory goes, you probably shouldn't be using UIKit for this. [Cocos2d](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) is better for games, and you can use [Box2d](http://www.box2d.org/) or [chipmunk](http://code.google.com/p/chipmunk-physics/) for physics.

Comment: Is there any tutorial on how to use Cocos2D on what not? I have a Cocos2D template on my xcode.

Comment: Google is your friend, check [this one](http://www.raywenderlich.com/352/how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-tutorial) out. And if you're satisfied with this answer, mark it as such.

Comment: I actually found that after I explored. Thanks.